# Esqueleto simple type error

Tags: haskell, yesod, esqueleto

I'm getting a type error with a query right from the [hackage page](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto-1.3.4.2/docs/Database-Esqueleto.html#t%3aValue).
The query is supposed to select a `GolfCourse` whose name is equal to `"Miniota"`.
Query:

```
getTestR :: Handler Html
getTestR = do
  gcs <- runDB $
          E.select $
          E.from $ \g -> do
          E.where_ (g E.^. GolfCourseName ==. E.val "Miniota")
          return g
  defaultLayout $(widgetFile "test")
```

The error:

```
Handler/Home.hs:713:49:
    Couldn't match expected type `Text' with actual type `E.Value typ0'
    Expected type: E.Value Text
      Actual type: E.Value (E.Value typ0)
    In the return type of a call of `E.val'
    In the second argument of `(==.)', namely `E.val "Miniota"'
```

I suspect that the error has to do with me incorrectly using `E.val`
I'm not actually using `gcs` in the widgetFile right now. Help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain, but it *might* be that you need to use:

```
... E.==. E.val ...
```

Since the exact problem depends on your import statements, it's probably a good idea to provide a link to a complete, standalone file demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!  I forgot that Persistent's `==.` and Esqueleto's `==.` were different.